# Vector files in QGIS are very badly deformed in different projection systems

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, antimeridian

I have a vector file of a world map, a shapefile.  I wanted to make a map of the world centered on the Pacific Ocean, so I used EPSG:8859  BUT the Arctic and Antarctic regions will undergo severe deformation.

[image]

The CRS was changed to EPSG:4326, and some locations were also very badly deformed.

[image]

If I changed the CRS to ESRI:102035, the graphics would look normal, but that's not what I wanted.

[image]

How should I get the right settings?